# Ignore blank searches in GUI using Java and SQL

Tags: java, sql, user-interface

I'm creating a GUI using java to let a user search from a table of cars. There are 7 fields to search from: VIN, brand, model, year, mileage, price, and color. The user can choose any combination from one to all the fields to search for a car.

Depending on which combination the user leaves blank I'm using:

```
select * from Cars where color = '"+color+"'"
```

or

```
select * from Cars where mileage = '"+mileage1+"' and color = '"+color+"'
```

But given 7 fields there are 128 total combinations. Do I have to implement all possible combinations? Or is there a way that SQL can ignore when the user leaves one or more fields blank?

Answer (score 2):

```
public class Filter {
    private final Set<String> fields;
    private final Map<String, String> search;

    public Filter(String ... fields) {
        this.fields = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(fields));
    }

    public void addSearch(String field, String value) {
        if (field != null && value != null && fields.contains(field)) {
            search.put(field, value);
        }
    }

    public String toSQL() {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : search) {
            String field = entry.getKey(), value = entry.getValue();
            if (builder.length() == 0) {
                builder.append("WHERE ");
            } else {
                builder.append("AND ");
            }
            builder.append(field).append(" = '").append(value).append("'")
        }
        return builder.toString();
    }
}
```

This is a very simple solution which you surely can improve on.
Use it like this:

```
Filter filter = new Filter("color", "mileage" /* and other columns */);
filter.addSearch("color", color);

String sql = "SELECT * FROM Cars " + filter.toSQL();
```

You should probably check the user input to protect against SQL injection and other possible misuses.

Another more professional solution is "Object Relational Mapping", in Java with [JPA](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/tech/persistence-jsp-140049.html). Google "JPA", "Criteria API", "Hibernate" or "ORM".

Answer (score 0):

just contruct your sql statement, when field is filled you add to sql string

```
    sql = "select * from Cars where"
    if(field1.text.toString().trim().compareTo("") == 0) sql = sql + field1;
```

etc
Dont forget the "and"
*** Edit : never trust user input (sql injection) ***